# App crashes while running

Tags: android, sqlite, package, rename

I have a full fledged  app ...I  renamed its package name ... and tried to run but after displaying the first page it get crashed..

here is my logcat:

```
815-2815/com.Bubbles E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such table: centers
08-06 14:12:22.164    2815-2815/com.Bubbles D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-06 14:12:22.165    2815-2815/com.Bubbles E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.Bubbles, PID: 2815
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: centers (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  *  FROM centers where centername='Delhi'
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
            at com.Bubbles.database.DataBaseHelper.getCityCode(DataBaseHelper.java:413)
            at com.Bubbles.Login.GetCityCode(Login.java:233)
            at com.Bubbles.Login.Insertvalues(Login.java:175)
            at com.Bubbles.Login.access$400(Login.java:26)
            at com.Bubbles.Login$3.onClick(Login.java:144)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

waiting for a help..thanks in advance

Comment: seriously ? `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: centers`

Comment: post your table creation code.

Answer (score 2):

You did more things than package rename as the real cause is:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: centers
```

Comment: And any solutions pls

Comment: Do not use tables you do not have or check your DB Helper `onCreate()` to ensure it creates all tables your app is expecting.

Comment: checked my oncreate()...no tables found extra

Comment: Your app crashes because you try to access table you do not have in database. So do your homework and check what you are doing wrong - you forgot to create it? you are accessing wrong table? do you have database initialized at all? there's no magic.